# PHP - setup PHING

Tags: php

i'm very noob

i want to work with PHING , but my php not have this ext

i download phing-2.4.2.zip from http://phing.info/trac/wiki/Users/Download

but i don't know to import PHING to php :(

help me ! thank !

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Phing has a guide:

http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/

Comment: if youre new to PHP youll probably want to use the `PEAR` install. less hassle.

Comment: but i don't know to use pear :(

Comment: Are you using a shared host or a dedicated server/your own computer?

Comment: no. i use my local computer. I use XAMPP1.6.8 , how to use Phing with this version.